# How to make crossdomain calls in Android or phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, cross-domain

I want to make a crossdomain call for an Android app. I have tried using it in the native and also on the phonegap but am not able to make it.

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

On Your Project `-> res -> xml ->config.xml`

Replace `< access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/>`

To `< access origin="*"/>`

Answer (score -1):

Just make some change to @Amit Prajapati comment like below :

Replace this

```
< access origin="*"/>
```

To

```
< access origin=".*"/>
```